# Query Archived Cases Information in Apex, Salesforce

Tags: salesforce, apex, salesforce-lightning, soql

I am trying to query archived cases in Apex in Salesforce

select count() from Case where ContactId = Id ALL ROWS

My contact has 7 active cases and 8 archived cases. But it still shows number 7 instead of 15. Is there any way can you please tell me how to get archived case information.

Comment: What do you mean by archiving Cases, do you have any links to SF help or Trailhead describing this feature? I know Activities (tasks, events) and old field history tracking can be archived but never heard of archiving Cases. You're sure your company didn't build something custom, with special custom object, "big objects", or even "external objects" (data stored on another server, silently fetched on the fly when you view the contact)? There's https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000Gdd1kUAB/archive-closed-cases but closed...